# Does raising a PR to two different branches at the same time causes issues in github?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

I have two branches `A` and `master`. `A` branch is ahead of `master` by several commits. I took the pull of the `master` and created a new branch `fixes` out of it, did some changes and pushed it. Now I raised two `PR` from that branch. One to `master` and another one to `A`. As soon as I raised PR to `A`, the first PR which I created to `master` started showing additional commits to merge which were present on `A`.My branch `fixes` was from `master` only and had no additional commits of `A`. So how come it was showing additional commits of `A` by which it was ahead, to merge into `master`.

I was not able to reproduce this thing every time. I tried this doing 10 times and saw this thing happening 2 times only. What is the reason for it.

UPDATE.
See this scenario 
[image]

This PR was raised to `dw-backend`. But this PR is in `master`.

And this is my master history after this commit.

```
* 6bce034 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge pull request #293 from stockarea/testing
* 30824d7 Merge pull request #276 from stockarea/aashish-new-seo
* 091a8ab LaravelLoggerServiceProvider checking
* 3238cb8 Merge pull request #272 from stockarea/aashish-cr-admin
* cd8a730 Merge pull request #269 from stockarea/aashish-sitemap
* 5512440 Merge pull request #267 from stockarea/aashish-sitemap
* 3099ab4 Merge pull request #259 from stockarea/karthick-backend-fix
* bcc1afa updated-package.json
* f4c17f1 fine
* abbb287 Merge branch 'master' into develop-dw
* 2df3f48 develop+master
* 6937e13 Merge pull request #209 from stockarea/A-rfp-bugfix
```

After PR #209 neither `dw-backend` was merged into it, neither any branch which was created out of it. All above branch which are merged into it were made out of `master` only for hot production fixes.

Comment: Because my master branch is in production and other branch is on develop server.. So I want to keep track on both branches

Comment: I dont' want to merge directly to master from develop, as develop will be under working condition and some things which we can't release on master(aka production)

Comment: You mean by cherrypicking?

Comment: Apart from this discussion @matt. Can you answer the question rather than workaround

Comment: Is there any solution or reason for my question??

Comment: You might get better help (though not from me, sorry) if you were more specific. First of all, it matters greatly _which_ remote interface you are using, as they all implement pull requests differently from one another. Remember, this is not a git feature; it's something that each remote interface does. So you need to specify that. Second, you should show the actual interface listing the commits, to show how the problem is manifested.

Comment: @AbhirajTulsyan `git log --decorate --graph --all` would help to understand just what's going on. As well as some screenshots of the PRs.

Comment: @matt. Have updated my answer and tried to explain what had happened.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it's apparent `fixes` is a hot patch to production (master) and A is either a feature branch (good) or a long-lived development branch (hopefully not).

> I have two branches A and master. A branch is ahead of master by several commits. I took the pull of the master and created a new branch fixes out of it, did some changes and pushed it.

Assuming there were changes to master between when A was created and when fixes was created, and some more changes to master, your repo looks like this.

```
              7 - 8 [fixes]
             /
1 - 2 - 5 - 6 - 9 - 10 [master]
     \
      3 - 4 [A]
```

> Now I raised two PR from that branch. One to master and another one to A. As soon as I raised PR to A, the first PR which I created to master started showing additional commits to merge which were present on A

Merging fixes onto master will merge commits 7 and 8 from fixes.

```
              7 - 8 --- [fixes]
             /         \
1 - 2 - 5 - 6 - 9 - 10 - M [master]
     \
      3 - 4 [A]
```

Merging fixes onto A will merge commits 7 and 8 from fixes *as well as* 5 and 6 from master. This is because A is split off master at an earlier point than fixes is. If we rearrange the graph a bit to center it on A this becomes more obvious.

```
# Same repository visualized differently
            9 - 10 [master]
           /
      5 - 6 - 7 - 8 [fixes]
     /
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 [A] 

$ git merge fixes A

            9 - 10 [master]
           /
      5 - 6 - 7 - 8 [fixes]
     /             \
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 ----- M [A]
```

> As soon as I raised PR to A, the first PR which I created to master started showing additional commits to merge which were present on A

I don't know why that would happen. I expect we're missing a piece of information. Anyway, this should not be handled with two PRs.

---

The simple solution is to first merge fixes into master, then update A from master and continue developing A.

```
              7 - 8 --- [fixes]
             /         \
1 - 2 - 5 - 6 - 9 - 10 - M [master]
     \                    \
      3 - 4 -------------- N [A]
```

This ensures that `fixes` goes through the whole QA process, where it may change or be rejected, before you build on top of it.

---

If you need those fixes ***now***, one solution is to  [cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) just 7 and 8 onto A.

```
git checkout A
git cherry-pick master...fixes

              7 - 8 --- [fixes]
             /         \
1 - 2 - 5 - 6 - 9 - 10 - M [master]
     \
      3 - 4 - 7A - 8A [A]
```

This sort of cross-branch surgery is a recipe for headaches. I recommend against it.

Instead, if you can't wait for `fixes` to complete the PR process, I'd recommend rebasing `A` on top of `fixes`.

```
              7 - 8 [fixes]
             /
1 - 2 - 5 - 6 - 9 - 10 [master]
     \
      3 - 4 [A]

git checkout A
git rebase fixes

                    3A - 4A [A]
                   /
              7 - 8 [fixes]
             /
1 - 2 - 5 - 6 - 9 - 10 [master]
```

If `fixes` changes during the review process, you can just rebase again.

```
                    3A - 4A [A]
                   /
              7 - 8 - 11 - 12 [fixes]
             /
1 - 2 - 5 - 6 - 9 - 10 [master]

git rebase fixes

                              3B - 4B [A]
                             /
              7 - 8 - 11 - 12 [fixes]
             /
1 - 2 - 5 - 6 - 9 - 10 [master]
```

And once fixes is merged into master, merge from master into A.

```
# fixes has been merged

              7 - 8 - 11 - 12 - 3B - 4B [A]
             /               \
1 - 2 - 5 - 6 - 9 - 10 ------ M [master]

git merge master A

              7 - 8 - 11 - 12 - 3B - 4B - N [A]
             /               \          /
1 - 2 - 5 - 6 - 9 - 10 ------ M -------- [master]
```

Comment: Have updated my question. See if its giving better clarity.

Comment: @AbhirajTulsyan PR #195 was merged into dw-backend. Then I presume dw-backend got merged into master. Again, `git log --decorate --graph --oneline --all` will make it clear what's going on.

Comment: Ok will do it and will tell

Comment: No we never merged dw-backend into master.

Comment: @AbhirajTulsyan Do a `git fetch` to ensure you're up to date and then `git branch -a --contains 3db071c2c255dce` to be sure. If `master` or `remotes/origin/master` is not in there, I would recommend contacting Github support.

Comment: It is there. But I can't find any PR after that through which we merged it to master.

Comment: I know that this commit is there,that is the only question how did it came in this

Comment: @AbhirajTulsyan PRs and Github will only tell you so much because they lie about the history. So does `git log` without `--graph`. Git history is not linear, it is a "graph" of connected commits like my drawings above. `git log --graph --decorate --oneline 3db071c2c255dce^..master` should show you how its got there. `3db071c2c255dce^..master` is all commits reachable by master except those reachable by the commit before 3db071c2c255dce. So it will show you everything in master from 3db071c2c255dce forward. See [`gitrevisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for more.

Comment: Please see my updated question description. It will help track it better.

Comment: @AbhirajTulsyan A merge should have two parent connections. Yours have only one. This is confusing and could happen for any number of reasons. Please be very clear what command you're running so we know what we're looking at. Again, `git log --graph --decorate --oneline 3db071c2c255dce^..master` should show how 3db071c2c255dce got into master. If it's too large use [a secret gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/stockarea/feca211d679f56ee989c1248ee25c311. I ran `git log --graph --oneline 6937e139e81^..master` as per my new question description

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216010/discussion-between-abhiraj-tulsyan-and-schwern).

Comment: @AbhirajTulsyan 6937e139e81 was merged into develop. develop was merged into master. Full answer is in chat.